# My copy of Azure database seems to be synced with the original

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm new to the subject but I needed a copy of an Azure database to try some improvements on views.
I managed to make the copy but now I notice that the data is synced, i.e. new data in the original database is also found in the copy.
I used the restore function of the Azure Portal. Just gave the database a name and executed.
Now I'm confused and reluctant to make any changes. Is this really a copy? I don't mind the sync but can it be switched off?

Comment: Where are you viewing or working with the databases? When you say synced, you mean after you did the copy/restore data that is added to the original after that is now also showing up in the copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was assured within my company that there is no test environment there was a server running and I happened to give the copy database wrong/right name.
For years this server was logging errors until a database popped up with the right name.
Sorry to confuse you all and myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Copy option of the portal does not keep the copy of the database in sync with the original database.

Another option you can do is to choose [Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export) on the Azure portal menu for that database. It will export the database as a bacpac to an Azure Storage Account. After that you can [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell) the bacpac and create a new Azure SQL Database from that bacpac or you can download that bacpac to a local computer and imported to a local SQL Server instance.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for your answer. I just found out that the database wasn't created from a copy but from a restore. Still I can't find no reference to why it is synced and if it's definitely a separate database.

Comment: Maybe the database has external tables (external data sources defined). https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: Ne external data, But now I'm wondering: Could it be that, since I'm using Management Studio (MS) and the original DB is called KBI and the copy KBI_Test, that MS is confused about the names. I'm confused anyway how I I'll have to get both DB's in MS. I succeed howver but the way I'm doing this is strange to me. I add the other when connected to the first and then it remambers the last i've added and the next time it's the other way round. I'll rename the copy to something different and let you know.

Comment: Although I was assured that there is no test environment there was a server running and I happened to give the copy database wrong/right name. Crazy coincidence. Thanks anyway Alberto to give your time. Case closed.

Comment: I am glad for you. Thank you for sharing the end of this case with us.